# FQL - Getting list of friends of same or opposite sex

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I want to get list of user's friends, but gender wise, in 1 call. Like friends with the same gender as the user or friends of opposite gender. Currently, I have to make 2 calls for this. First, to fetch the user's gender and second to get the list like this

```
SELECT uid, name 
  FROM user 
 WHERE uid IN (
             SELECT uid2 
               FROM friend 
              WHERE uid1 =me()
              ) 
   AND sex='< gender >'
```

Comment: That's cool. But what's the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned it in the question. I want to know if its possible to do it in 1 call. By some fql keyword. Like there are keywords like 'meeting_sex' and many others. Network calls hurt the realtime-feel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get friends that have the same gender as you is as follow:

To get your gender:
`select sex from user where uid = me()`

To get all friends:
`select uid, sex from user where uid in (select uid1 from friend where uid2 = me())`

And the combination of both:

```
select uid, sex from user where 
uid in 
(
    select uid1 from friend where uid2 = me()
) 
and 
sex in 
(
    select sex from user where uid = me()
)
```

EDIT

For opposite gender

```
select uid, sex from user where 
uid in 
(
    select uid1 from friend where uid2 = me()
) 
and not(sex in 
(
    select sex from user where uid = me()
))
```

This will return you all friends with the same / opposite gender as you in **one** query.

Comment: Oh. I should have thought about it. Thanks .

Comment: Welcome :) And you explained your problem well. You can accept the answer :)

Comment: Edited the answer for opposite gender query.